# WordPress not syncing with FTP

Tags: ftp

This is the first time this happens to me.

I uploaded a WordPress theme via FTP to wp-content/themes and it's not showing on my WordPress backend.

I then deleted plugins from the backend and 1 theme then refreshed my FTP and they are still there.

It seems Wordpress isn't syncing with what there is in the FTP.

The WordPress folder has the 755 permission and index.php has 644.

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Honestly, it just sounds like your FTP is connected to the wrong site. WordPress _is_ the files that you see in FTP. It doesn't need to "sync" with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an issue with the filesize upload limit. The size should be below 30M. Follow these steps:

1. Find your php.ini file.
2. Use the following line:

   ```
   post_max_size = 8M 
   upload_max_filesize = 2M
   ```

If you can't get to your php.ini file, you can change the filesize upload limit with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/).